# "Propose that" or "propose for"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjunctive-mood

Can the sentence

> They proposed (**that**) the book be banned.

be rephrased as

> They proposed **for** the book to be banned.

If so, would it sound (very) informal?

Comment: It sounds funny if you say it with for.

Comment: I would say **no**, that’s not a grammatical rephrasing. Apart from simple noun phrases, _propose_ can take various different clause-like constructions as its object: gerund clauses, infinitival clauses, subordinate (often subjunctive) clauses. With subordinate clauses, there’s no trouble with having a different subject from the main subject; with gerund clauses, it just about works, but it’s a bit clumsy; and with infinitival clauses, for whatever reason, it’s downright ungrammatical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How about: "It was proposed for the book to be banned"? Would this one work?

Comment: Same structure as "It's interesting that the book be banned." / "It's interesting for the book to be banned."

Comment: @user129055 Nope, that doesn't work either. (And it's not the same structure as either of those two sentences—the “it was proposed” sentence is a passive construction, while the “it's interesting” sentences are active. Those are also ungrammatical, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best comparison is with **move for** (/ *move that*)

> **move for**: move for something
>
> to make a parliamentary or legal motion in favor of something. I move
>   for dismissal of the case against my client. My lawyer moved for a
>   recess of the trial.

[[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/move+for)]

> **move that**: *move* 11. propose, suggest, urge, recommend, request,
>   advocate, submit, put forward I moved that the case be dismissed.

[[Collins Thesaurus of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/move)]

But while **propose that** is standard, *propose for* has no entry in the McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. There are internet examples of the form 'He proposed for the company to pay expenses', but I'd consider these informal to non-standard.